# What's the idiomatic way to map vector according to the longest seq in clojure?

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

```
(map vector [1 2 3] [4 5])
```

will give:

```
([1 4] [2 5])
```

Here 3 is discarded.

What if I want to pad those too short seqs to the largest length automatically?

e.g.
What's the idiomatic way if I want to get

```
([1 4] [2 5] [3 nil])
```

Answer (score 14):

```
(defn map-all [f & colls]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (some seq colls)
     (cons (apply f (map first colls))
           (apply map-all f (map rest colls))))))

(map-all vector [1 2 3] [4 5])
;=> ([1 4] [2 5] [3 nil])
```